# Show if $f$ is a measurable function, then for any Borel set $B$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> How to formally show if $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function, then for any Borel set $B$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

The theorem I know is that if $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for any open set $G$, $f^{-1}(G)$ is measurable.

Intuitively, since $B$ is a combination of finite/countable union, finite/countable intersection, and complements of open sets, and $f^{-1}$ is exchangeable with all these set operations, i.e. $f^{-1}(\bigcup G_k) = \bigcup f^{-1}(G_k)$, $f^{-1}(\bigcap G_k) = \bigcap f^{-1}(G_k)$, $f^{-1}(G^C) = (f^{-1}(G))^C$, and since $f^{-1}(G_k)$ is measurable for any $k$, then the desired statement should hold.

But I don't know how to formally put this into a proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In proving things about sigma-algebra, top-down approach usually works better than bottom-up approach. Top-down approach means that you define some set satisfying the property you need to prove and then prove it is a sigma-algebra. Bottom-up approach means you figure out some basis element satisfying the property you want to prove and show everything is made of the basis.

Specifically, define $\mathcal{B}=\{B:B \text{ is Borel}, f^{-1}(B) \text{ is measurable}\}$.

Then show $\mathcal{B}$ is a sigma-algebra and contains all open sets. This shows $\mathcal{B}$ contains all the Borel sets.